# Disable calendar on input field on radio button select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a input box with ui calendar on it. I want to `disable` the `input` box so that the calendar doesn't open on user `focus` of mouse to the input field.

I have used `$('#enddate').attr('readonly', true);` to disable the input box, but still the calendar opens on clicking the input box.

The code snippet that I have used is as follows:

```
$('.starttime').click(function(){
    atype=$('input:radio[name=startdate]:checked').val();

    if(atype==2){
        $('#enddate').attr('readonly', true);
    }
    else
        $('#enddate').attr('readonly', false);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this man: http://jsfiddle.net/4U7BS/ **extra** in this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/VjadE/ (from date will not open the calendar because its `disabled` and to field will and I reckon thats what you want `:)`

I hope your DOM and rest Jquery is correct!

Hope it helps the cause!

**code**

```
$("#enddate").prop("disabled",true);
```

to enable

```
$("#enddate").prop("disabled",false);
```